# How to remove list element?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have two lists like below.

```
List<string> apple= new List<string>();
  apple.Add("a");
  apple.Add("b");

List<string> ball= new List<string>();
  ball.Add("a,b");
  ball.Add("b,c");
  ball.Add("c,a");
```

Now I want to remove elements from the `ball` list that of which there are  substrings of those elements in the `apple` list. That is if "a" occurs in `ball` list element, I have to remove those listelements from the `ball` list.

My expected output of ball list should be (b,c).

Answer (score 2):

Here a quick LinqPad

```
var apple= new List<string>();
apple.Add("a");

var ball= new List<string>();
ball.Add("a,b");
ball.Add("b,c");
ball.Add("c,a");

ball.Where(b=>apple.Any(b.Contains))
    .ToList() //create a duplicate, also lists have ForEach
    .ForEach(b=>ball.Remove(b));

ball.Dump();
```

Output is:

```
b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ball = ball.Where(b => !apple.Any(a => b.Contains(a))).ToList();
```

Comment: This will cause a compile time error. "Where" returns an IEnumerable but ball is a list. ToList is needed after Where. Also the request was to remove items from the list, not replace the list.